# if I use parity -d "path" to sync with a modify path.will i type -d again when next time open parity?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity

this is my first time to use parity, so if i just type parity -d \abc to sync in the folder named abc.  and should I type it again the next time I use the rpc service with parity? if not, will it sync again in default folder?

Answer (score 1):

you should be keep your -d option or add config yml to your path. example below:

```
parity --config=/config/parity.toml
```

in parity.toml, you can config data path as your satisfied way.you can generate this config file by this tools:
https://paritytech.github.io/parity-config-generator/